# plotting feature importances gives an error "arrays must all be same length"

Tags: python, arrays, plot

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
def plot_feature_importance(model):
    importance = pd.DataFrame({'Feature': list(X), 'Feature importance': model.feature_importances_})
    rank = importance.sort_values(by='Feature importance',ascending=False).head(30)
    plt.figure(figsize = (10,12))
    plt.title('Top 30 - Features importance - XGBoost',fontsize=14)
    s = sns.barplot(y='Feature',x='Feature importance',data=importance, orient='h')
    s.set_xticklabels(s.get_xticklabels(),rotation=90)
    plt.show()

plot_feature_importance(model)
```

Hi, I'm trying to get feature importance for a dataset (IBM HR attrition from kaggle), and i get an error when i try to create a plot. Here is the error message:

ValueError: arrays must all be same length

Comment: and here is the link to the full code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AebH4L_EouL6r5pMW7Y9rXll683HRcJw